# Using Conditional Operators inside push in Perl

Tags: perl, conditional-operator

I am new to Perl development and I wanted to check if using conditional operators inside a push statement is allowed.
Something like this

```
push(@myMap, {
    key1 => value1,
    key2 => value2,
    (condition)?{
        key3 => value3,
    }:(),
    key4 => value4
});
```

Basically I only want to add a value to a Map based on a condition

Comment: The easiest way to find out is to run the code.

Comment: You are not bound to do everything inside one statement. You can just add hash key/values later on, e.g. `$myMap[0]{key3} = "value3" if condition`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but your code is wrong.

```perl
push(@myMap, {
    key1 => value1,
    key2 => value2,

    (condition) ? 
      {                   ### these brackets are wrong
        key3 => value3,
      }                   ###
   :(),

    key4 => value4
});
```

If the condition is true, you are creating a data structure with an uneven number of elements. It will contain a single hash reference as one of the values, so you don't have key/value pairs anymore, and it might complain.

It will try to do what you want, basically turning that hash ref into its string representation, and then using `key4` as the value, leaving you with `value4` and `undef` as the last pair.

Fix:

```perl
push(@myMap, {
    key1 => value1,
    key2 => value2,
    (condition) ? ( key3 => value3 ) : (),
    key4 => value4
});
```

Comment: Couldn't this be a case for the Enterprise operator: `(key3 => value3) x !!(condition)` ?

Comment: @jo-37 that would work, but it's not exactly readable.

Comment: @simbabque, I'm not a big fan of it, but it's is a known idiom. That makes it defacto readable if the pattern can be recognized, and this one is easy to recognize. It's like I instantly know that we're doing something with duplicate if I see `!$seen{$_}++` near a `grep` or `if`. It's not cause I spent time parsing the expression; it's that it's a familiar pattern.